# MVC routing - why does my request not match the route?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I'm making a request that I thought would be caught by my route, but there is no match. What am I doing wrong?

Any comments appreciated,
Anders, Denmark

--

Url :

```
EventReponse/ComingAdmin/386/01e71c45-cb67-4711-a51f-df5fcb54bb8b
```

Expected match:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Editing event responses for other user", // Route name
            "EventResponse/{action}/{eventId}/{userId}", // URL with parameters
            new {controller = "EventResponse", action = "ComingAdmin"} // Parameter defaults
            );
```

Desired controller (but I guess this does not come into play):

```
public class EventResponseController : ControllerBase
{
    (...)
    public ActionResult ComingAdmin(int eventId, Guid userId)
    {
        return RegisterEventResponse(eventId, AttendanceStatus.Coming, userId);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your userId is not between curly braces

```
routes.MapRoute(
        "Editing event responses for other user", // Route name
        "EventResponse/{action}/{eventId}/{userId}", // URL with parameters
        new {controller = "EventResponse", action = "ComingAdmin"} // Parameter defaults
       );
```

And your Url mentions EventReponse instead of EventRe **s** ponse so it should be:

```
EventResponse/ComingAdmin/386/01e71c45-cb67-4711-a51f-df5fcb54bb8b
```

It's all in the details :-)

Comment: Good call - and fast!
Alas it did not solve the problem (in itself).

Comment: Fantastic - so it wasn't black voodoo after all! Thanks and have a nice day!